# Rails SQL Query returning count = 0 as count = 1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT distinct loan_cases.case_status, count(loan_applications.id) 
FROM "loan_cases" 
LEFT JOIN case_statuses 
  ON loan_cases.id = case_statuses.loan_case_id 
LEFT JOIN loan_applications 
  ON case_statuses.loan_application_id = loan_applications.id 
GROUP BY loan_cases.case_status;
```

This is my result set

```
        case_status          | count 
------------------------------+-------
 Completed (End)              |    28
 Need Special Attention       |     0
 Failed (End)                 | 11209
 Pending Submission           |  1720
 Pending Acceptance           |    12
 New                          |     2
 Pending Follow Up Call       |     2
 Pending Invoicing            |    63
 Submitted Requires Follow Up |     0
 Pending Evaluation           |    11
 Drop Off (End)               |   566
```

When i run the same query rails way

```
LoanCase.joins("LEFT JOIN case_statuses ON loan_cases.id = case_statuses.loan_case_id LEFT JOIN loan_applications ON case_statuses.loan_application_id = loan_applications.id").group("loan_cases.case_status").select("distinct loan_cases.case_status, count(loan_applications_views.id)").size
```

it returns this

```
=> {"Submitted Requires Follow Up"=>1,
 "Pending Evaluation"=>11,
 "Need Special Attention"=>1,
 "Failed (End)"=>11209,
 "Pending Submission"=>1720,
 "New"=>2,
 "Drop Off (End)"=>566,
 "Pending Invoicing"=>63,
 "Completed (End)"=>28,
 "Pending Follow Up Call"=>2,
 "Pending Acceptance"=>12}
```

Why does it change the count = 0 to count = 1?

Any help appreciated?

Comment: Run the query from rails console and see if the SQL query is exactly what you expect.

Comment: @makhan if i didnt run the query, would i post the question? stop looking for cheap reputation points

Comment: If you run it in console then copy paste the output query. Rails doesn't automagically add 1 to results. FYI there are no points for comments.

Comment: well as u would know @makhan sometimes stuffs happen in ur code that just baffles u, this is one of those scenarios hopefully by the end of it, we can learn something on how to solve it. I have output the result on console and on sql and those r d results.

Comment: I mean the SQL query: `2.1.5 :008 > Account.first`
  `DEBUG - 11/Mar/2015 14:42:32 Account Load (1.8ms)  SELECT 'accounts'.* FROM 'accounts' WHERE ('accounts'.deleted_at IS NULL) LIMIT 1`

Comment: dude pls just stop, u r nt helping at all @makhan

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but in your original query you are selecting `count(loan_applications.id)`, but in your rails query you are selecting `count(loan_applications_views.id)`. Have you tried changing your rails query to match your original query w.r.t. the column that you're counting?